# How to prevent Jest from reimporting of modules before each test suite?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have a factory function that creates database users with incrementing number in email address, since it is an unique field:

```
let a = 0;

function createUser() {
    User.create({
        email: `user-${a}@email.com`,
    });

    a++;
}
```

I use it in several test suites. It seems however that Jest's default test runner resets module cache before each suite and resets the counter, so I get unique index violations.

My workaround is to generate random email addresses. Is there any way to prevent module cache being reset? I don't see it documented anywhere.

Note: I run my tests with `--runInBand` to prevent various problems when working with database.

Comment: Using generated email address is a good option, maybe even with email address as uuids?